# TikZ-pgfplot Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/width', to which you pass

Tags: pgfplots

In the following minimal code, an error occurs with the the width and height  during compilation, giving a **4cm** width which appears to come from nowhere?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}[
     width=0.8\textwidth,
     height=0.8\textwidth,
    grid=major,
    grid style={gray!10},
    axis lines=middle, enlargelimits=false,
    inner axis line style={-latex},
    xlabel={\large $x$},
    ylabel={\large $y$ },
    ymin=-10, ymax=10,
    xmin=-10, xmax=10,
    xtick={-10,-9,...,10},   ytick={-10,-9,...,10},   
    xticklabel style={above,tiny},
    yticklabel style={left,tiny},      
]
\addplot [blue,mark=none] {9-3*x};
\end{axis}

%--------
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I have answered your question. Let me know.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
    font=\scriptsize,
    x=1cm*1,
    y=1cm*1,
    axis x line=center,
    axis y line=center,
    x axis line style={->},
    y axis line style={->},
    xtick={-10,-9,...,10},
    ytick={-10,-9,...,10},
    xlabel style={below},
    ylabel style={left},
    xmin=-10, xmax=10,
    ymin=-10, ymax=10,
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[scale=0.75]
\plot[blue,mark=none,domain=-6:6] {9-3*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

It's because of these keys

```
xticklabel style={above,tiny},
yticklabel style={left,tiny}
```

`tiny` is an axis command which makes a, ehm, tiny plot with 4cm width. You are using probably to make the text of the label to be `tiny` which needs to have the `font` key, say, `font=\tiny`.

The description of `tiny` is in Section 4.10.2

Comment: +1 for your answer. Very good. I hope to understand the question. My English is very bad. :-( sorry.

Comment: many thanks to you. Spent hours to understand.